# NGINX not executing php files

Tags: php, nginx

First at all I am new here and new to unix. My previous experience was solely with cPanel, Plesk etc. So please forgive me if there are some mistakes in my approach here.

I have a Centos (release 7.3.1611) VPS with Nginx (1.10.2) and PHP (7.0.17).

I followed some guides to get PHP running and followed some answers given here to similar problems as well to no avail.

Here is my configuration:

www.conf:

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

I changed permission and ownership on php-fpm.sock.

nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
```

nginx/default.d/default.conf:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name _; 
location ~ \.php$ { 
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; 
fastcgi_index index.php; 
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
include fastcgi_params; 
}
```

Finally I have created a info.php file. When executing it I am getting a nginx error: The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

If disabling the nginx error page the browser is asking me if I want to download the file info.php.

Thank you for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

I initially encountered similar issues but fixed by making sure the path to 'include' and 'fastcgi_pass' were valid. You can verify if something is available at these paths by navigating to those directories.

```
# PHP 7
# cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 in php.ini
# case-sensitive regex
location ~ \.php$ {
    include         /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    try_files       $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Ian

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ian. The path to fastcgi_pass is correct in nginx/default.d/default.conf. The pass to include was not. It should be /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params. I have corrected the default.conf accordingly, but still no luck.

Comment: Any messages in the nginx error.log? Specifically at the same time when you're trying to access a PHP file through the browser?